# What is the Django-way of namespacing ModelAdmin.get_urls when using model(admin) inheritance?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, namespaces, django-admin

## TL;DR

Is there a way to have (namespaced,) well-named views defined when using `ModelAdmin.get_urls` and `ModelAdmins` extended by inheritance?

Preferably without resorting to `ModelAdmin.model._meta` or some other solution of slightly questionable nature.

## Pretext

View names added through `get_urls` get overridden when using and inheriting from custom `ModelAdmins`.

That is, the view name `admin:tighten` gets overriden in the following example:

```
class Screw(models.Model):
    "A screw"

class HexCapScrew(Screw):
    "A hex cap screw"


class ScrewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(ScrewAdmin, self).get_urls()
        extra_urls = patterns('',
            url(r'^tighten/$', self.tighten, name='tighten'),
        )
        return extra_urls + urls

    def tighten(self, request):
        pass

class HexCapScrewAdmin(ScrewAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Screw, ScrewAdmin)
admin.site.register(HexCapScrew, HexCapScrewAdmin)
```

On shell the following happens:

```
In [1]: reverse('admin:tighten')
Out[1]: u'/admin/parts/hexscrew/tighten/'
```

This is of course understandable since the registration of `HexCapScrewAdmin` overides the `tighten` in `ScrewAdmin` however now it's impossible to reverse `ScrewAdmin.tighten`.

## A preferred solution

However I would like to be able to

1. reference both views separatedly and
2. preferably have views in their own instance namespaces.

## Progress so far

The best I've come up with is the following setup (can be copy&pasted directly to some app for testing):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models

class Screw(models.Model):
    "A screw"
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'parts'


class HexCapScrew(Screw):
    "A hex cap screw"
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'parts'
        proxy = True


class ScrewAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def tighten(self, request):
        pass

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(ScrewAdmin, self).get_urls()
        extra_urls = patterns('',
            url(r'^tighten/$', self.tighten, name='tighten'),
        )
        # Find out the slugified name of the model this admin is bound to
        # TODO: Feels dirty
        model_name = self.model._meta.model_name

        # Add the to `extra_urls` to their own namespace
        namespaced_extra_urls = patterns('',
            url(r'^', include(extra_urls, namespace=model_name, app_name='screw')),
        )
        return namespaced_extra_urls + urls


class HexCapScrewAdmin(ScrewAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Screw, ScrewAdmin)
admin.site.register(HexCapScrew, HexCapScrewAdmin)
```

Now I have the following:

```
In [1]: reverse('admin:screw:tighten')
Out[1]: u'/admin/parts/screw/tighten/'

In [2]: reverse('admin:hexscrew:tighten')
Out[2]: u'/admin/parts/hexscrew/tighten/'

In [3]: reverse('admin:screw:tighten', current_app='hexscrew')
Out[3]: u'/admin/parts/hexscrew/tighten/'
```

which is nice and works but includes a bit of hackery.

Is this the best that's available or am I just missing something? Any suggestions?

(At least one other way would be to do as Django's `ModelAdmin.get_urls` use `ModelAdmin.model._meta` to [parametrize the view names](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e23de9e350d716c4d9ebe0b27c9f2752fe1aa543/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L463) but then I would use the namespaces.)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the way the admin does it [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L573), you will see that in addition to defining the url, the model admin also prefixes the app_label and model_name to the url name, thus avoiding the subclassing issue to begin with. It also has the advantage of securing the view against unauthorised users (using the `self.admin_site.admin_view` decorator). Your `get_urls()` method would then become:

```
 def get_urls(self):
     from django.conf.urls import url

     def wrap(view):
         def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
             return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
         return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

     info = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name

     urlpatterns = super(ScrewAdmin, self).get_urls()
     urlpatterns.append(
         url(r'^tighten/$', wrap(self.tighten), name='%s_%s_tighten' % info))
     return urlpatterns
```

Then, you'd look up your url like: `reverse('admin:app_screw_tighten')` or `reverse('admin:app_hex_screw_tighten')`.